# Need to decide between a trigger, CASE, END-ELSE to write to a table & DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

Bear with me here.  I used the script found at:
http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/replication-monitor/

I want to test to see if an entry been made from the server over the last 30 minutes?

If the answer is NO, then write that entry to a different table and possibly alert us.

The following query me the difference in minutes between right now and the very last entry for the server Test1 under 'monitorDate', a datetime field.

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF (minute, (SELECT TOP 1 (SELECT MAX(monitorDate) 
    FROM dba_replicationMonitor)), GETDATE())
FROM MASTER.dbo.dba_replicationMonitor
WHERE publicationName = 'Test1'
```

I can't figure out how to say 'if that number returned is more than 5, pass the serverName and monitorDate to a different table.

Any suggestions to point the way would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Soner, I look fwd to discussing ideas with you.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just derive your results and insert them if they match your needs?

```
INSERT INTO WHATEVERTABLE (serverfield, datefield)
SELECT result.server, result.date
FROM (YOURQUERY) result
WHERE result.yourresult > 5
```

Comment: Telarian, I'm going to give that a go right now and let you know what I find out, thanks.

Comment: Telarian, you got it right on the head with the result.yourresult > 5.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. You should mark my answer as correct then. ;)

Comment: first time on Stackoverflow, what's the method to do so here ;)

Comment: lol, I actually don't know. I've only ever asked one question and nobody has ever answered it. I assumed it was obvious.

Comment: You should see grayed out check marks on each answer and you click onthe the one you are accepting.